# Run a local stylus node?

Tags: arbitrum, rust, stylus

Is there a [anvil](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry) equivalence for [stylus](https://arbitrum.io/stylus)?

ie: I want to test my stylus smart contracts against a local stylus node, how would I do that?

Comment: I see you have a lot of Stylus related questions. Isn't there some Discord for it, or are they guiding people to ask here?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen the discord currently doesn't have the answers, and even if it did, it's much better to have this information indexed here so developers can easily find it in the future.

Comment: Agreed. Discord is a pit of knowledge forever unseen. We should use an indexing forum as much as possible. Looks like some of these questions don't have answers yet, or the answer is "no". I think it makes sense to leave them here for the time being till they have answers.